FALLA DE COMPARACIÓN ENTRE DOUBLES AÚN CUANDO SON EXACTAMENTE IGUALES
Tengo un problema que no logro comprender, tengo un programa que recibe datos numericos Double del usuario y deseo revisar si hay moda en esos datos en una cadena, el problema es que al intentar compararlos con dos ciclos FOR no realiza una comparación valida y ¿no se porqué ocurre esto?, ordene al codigo imprimir el evento dentro del FOR para verificar el error y opera de la siguiente manera.
    for(i=0; i<h; i++){
    Double a = datosuno[i];
    for(int j=0; j<h; j++){
    Double b = datosuno[j];
    if(a == b){
    System.out.println("yes");
    }else{System.out.println("no");
    }
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    }

este es solo un simple codigo que compara la lista de datos ingresados, pero solo si se trata de exactamente el mismo indice del array lo considera valido.
h = cantidad de datos (5) para el ejemplo
datosuno[] =  contiene los valores asignados por el usuario
a & b es un intento para contener los valores como estrategia, sin embargo, ocurre lo mismo que si solo comparara los valores datosuno[i] == datosuno[j] no hay diferencia y el resultado no es el esperado
por ejemplo digito
1.0
2.0
3.0
1.0
1.0
debería al hacer comparación liberar
yes
no
no
yes
yes
no
yes
no
no
no
no no yes no no
... etc
sin embargo, ocurre:
yes no no no no
no yes no no no
no no yes no no
... etc
Por que razón ocurre esto, o sí ¿acaso debo comparar de otra manera?

Cuando comparas arrays en la forma a == b en realidad estas comparando si apuntan a la misma dirección, no el valor en si, para comparar el valor debes utilizar el método equals. Arrays.equals(a, b)

En Java, cuando usas el operador ==, lo que se está comparando es el valor que hay en la variable.
Eso significa, en el caso de cualquier objeto, que se está comparando si la variable apunta al mismo objeto (porque toda variable cuyo tipo sea una clase realmente guarda un puntero a una instancia de dicha clase o el valor null).
Para comparar dos objetos se debe usar el método equals1.
En el caso particular que nos ocupa, Double es un wrapper del tipo primitivo double, que tiene un comportamiento especial2: el autoboxing. Esto permite operaciones como:
Double d=1.0; //Se guarda un double en su "envoltura" o wrapper
double primitiveDouble=d; //Se saca de la "envoltura"

Por tanto, podrías solucionar el problema declarando las variables como double:
for(i=0; i<h; i++){
    double a = datosuno[i];
    for(int j=0; j<h; j++){
        double b = datosuno[j];
        if(a == b){
            System.out.println("yes");
        }else{
            System.out.println("no");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}

1:Eso significa que el objeto debe haber implementado dicho método.
2: Todos los tipos primitivos lo tienen, incluidos byte y char
